# Robotium: How to launch an application with different process specified

Tags: process, robotium

Now, I want to write a test project which can launch a application which has below AndroidManifest(Key contents for package and activity).

> ```
> </package="com.mobitest.app"
> android:multiprocess="false" android:authorities="com.mobitest.app.search"
> provider android:name="com.mobitest.app.mail.provider.AttachmentProvider"
> ```
>
> android:label="@string/app_name"
>   android:name="com.mobitest.app.FileBrowser"
>   android:taskAffinity="com.mobitest.app.filebrowser"
>   android:value="com.mobitest.app.search.FileSearchActivity" />

### The info in my test project is as follows:

```
    public class TestApk extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2{
        private static final String TARGET_PACKAGE_ID="com.mobitest.app";
        private static final String LAUNCHER_ACTIVITY_FULL_CLASSNAME="com.mobitest.app.FileBrowser";
}
```

---

And I also changed the target pakage in the manifest as follows:

```
</android:targetPackage="com.mobitest.app" />
```

When I run the test, it always says that they are in different process.
I can know that tested app runs in browser process.
But for such app, how can I write test case to make it can be tested with Rbitium?

Any help is appreciated!